# How to Solve ORA-12560: TNS protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

[image]

I have tried restarting multiple times the services but I failed. Because of this error I cant install oracle apex.

Answer (score 0):

Try sys as sysdba. Look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6Fz2tqQqps).